# the Label Frame is getting wider that I don't

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using Python 3.11.0a5 as my platform. How do I get really `LabelFrame` to draw actually size in column 1? Unfortunately, I am having trouble understanding how to work around `columnspan`, `rowspan`, etc.

Here is pics:

[image]

Unfortunately, I don't want the LabelFrame to draw wider. Here is pics.
[image]

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#Create an instance of tkinter frame
win= Tk()

#Define the geometry of the window
win.geometry("400x160")

lblChannelName = ttk.Label(win, text='Channel Name')
lblChannelName.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='W')

entry_channelname = ttk.Entry(win, width=45)
entry_channelname.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='W')
 
lblChannelTopic = ttk.Label(win, text = 'Channel Topic')
lblChannelTopic.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=2, sticky='W')

entry_channelTopic = ttk.Entry(win, width=45)
entry_channelTopic.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2, sticky='W')

#Initialize a LabelFrame Widget
labelframe = LabelFrame(win, width=400, height=200, bd=5)
labelframe.grid(row=3, padx=2, pady=5, columnspan=18, sticky='WE')

#Checkbutton Invite
invite = IntVar()
ck1 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Invite Only[+i]', variable=invite)
ck1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, sticky='W')

#Checkbutton Moderated 
moderated = IntVar()
ck2 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Moderated[+m]', variable=moderated)
ck2.grid(row=0, padx=170, columnspan=3, sticky='W')

#Checkbutton Message
message = IntVar()
ck3 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='No Outside Message[+n]', variable=message)
ck3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='W')

#Checkbutton Private
private = IntVar()
ck4 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Private[+p]', variable=private)
ck4.grid(row=1, padx=170, columnspan=3, sticky='W')
 
#Checkbutton Only ops
topics = IntVar()
ck5 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Only ops set topics[+t]', variable=topics)
ck5.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='W')

#Checkbutton Secret Channel
secret = IntVar()
ck6 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Secret Channel[+s]', variable=secret)
ck6.grid(row=2, padx=170, columnspan=3, sticky='W')

#Checkbutton Keyed
keyed = IntVar()
ck7 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Channel is keyed[+k]', variable=keyed)
ck7.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='W')

lblkeyed = ttk.Label(labelframe, text='Key:')
lblkeyed.grid(row=3, padx=135, columnspan=2, sticky='W')

entry_keyed = ttk.Entry(labelframe, width=20)
entry_keyed.grid(row=3,  padx=170, columnspan=3, sticky='W')
 
#Checkbutton limit
limit = IntVar()
ck8 = ttk.Checkbutton(labelframe, text ='Limit channel members[+l]', variable=limit)
ck8.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='W')

win.mainloop()
```

How can I fix the Labe Frame in pics 1?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, when  you grid `labelframe`, change the `columnspan` to `2`. Line 24 will look like this:

```py
labelframe.grid(row=3, padx=2, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky='WE')
```

That will set your `LabelFrame` to the right width.

If you want the entries to align with the `LabelFrame`, you can make them `sticky='WE'`. Lines 14 and 20 would look like this:

```py
# Line 14
entry_channelname.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='WE')
```

```py
# Line 20
entry_channelTopic.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=2, sticky='WE')
```